# Unable to increase monitor resolution

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

Hi i have a Dell U2711 monitor connected to my PC. I am trying to set resolution to maximum supported of 2560x1440. Using DVI cable(tried VGA, HDMI as well). But Ubuntu 17.04 wouldn't let me. Have a Intel onboard graphics controller.
I tried adding resolution mode manually using xrandr:

```
cvt 2560 1440 30
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_30.00" 146.25 2560 2680 2944 3328 1440 1443 1448 1468 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440_30.00
```

But when i switch to this resolution with

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440_30.00
```

Screen blanks out and returns to old resolution. When i examine Xorg.0.log it just seems to have switched to that resolution and returned back with no errors. It did work once, not sure how, but not anymore.
If i do switching the resolution from the GUI settings, it just seems to be trying variety of modes(observed on Xorg logs).

```
root@buildbox:~# lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Xorg.0.log: when changing output

```
[  2531.162] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 2560x1440
[  2531.174] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@29.9 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2531.409] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1920x1200
[  2531.409] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1200@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

How do i get it to work?

[When i get resolution changed without returning to old resolution, this is how it ends up with no UI response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1D7y.jpg)

Comment: For a while i even had resolution changed, but screen with multiple copies of desktop tiled with no response in UI although mouse was functional.

Comment: The monitor's native resolution is the only one you should use. You may use less but the results are often quite bad and no, you can't go higher than the native resolution, no matter what you do or use.

Comment: My monitor do support this resolution, i can get this resolution on connected to a windows laptop on a DisplayPort

Comment: Ok i found a solution myself. But dont know why this have to be this way.
First run it on 60Hz once, it will fail as 60Hz rate isnt supported on DVI single link. Observable on the Xorg.0.log
Then run it on 30Hz, voila now it works!

Tested this on multiple restarts, repeatable all the time

Not sure why its happening this way, weird.

Comment: Congrats and upvotes. Weird but if it works... I don't know why either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found a solution myself. But dont know why this have to be this way. First run it on 60Hz once, it will fail as 60Hz rate isnt supported on DVI single link. Observable on the Xorg.0.log Then run it on 30Hz, voila now it works! Tested this on multiple restarts, repeatable all the time Not sure why its happening this way, weird.